# How does the borg queen keep coming back to life?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg, star-trek-first-contact, star-trek-picard

How does the borg queen keep coming back to life? She is killed but always reappears later.
When Picard asks her about this, she says Picard is thinking so 3-dimensionally.

Comment: The actress who played the queen in first contact also played her in the voyager finale.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/was-st-first-contact-borg-queen-a-different-one-from-st-voyager-borg-queen

Comment: The Borg queen is a function of the collective. When "she" needs a body, she's downloaded into one.

Comment: Good backup practices prevent data loss.  ;)

Comment: Like others have said, her body is likely just a way to interact with the physical world but she can be in many places at once via the collective

Answer (score 4):

According to [Star Trek Legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Legacy), the Borg seem to make queens as required, noting that it shows a bunch of identical females being borgified.

Presumably when one is killed, they just grow another one from the same genetic stock and make her their queen. Possibly they already have a few spares knocking around, in stasis, should the need should arise.

[image]